# strophe.js and openfire who terminates connection on page reload?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, symfony

I am using symfony2 to build some app. In that app I have chat app. I am using attached session in chat.

1) On login I fire up event listener to catch user/pass from login, connect to openfire server and get sid and rid.

2) After that i am storing that data in session so I can use them later on every page where I have chat.

Problem occurs when page is reloaded/refreshed.

My guess this is because ajax request to url:7070/httpd-bind is canceled strophe sends terminate to openfire server. Bu I can not find anywhere terminate stanza.

I am have patched strophe.js to use sync on page unload but again that is not working.

```
Chat.connection.flush();
Chat.connection.sync = true; // Switch to using synchronous requests since this is typically called onUnload.

Chat.connection.disconnect();
```

Please suggest solution for this, I am on 10 hour coding and I have no idea how to solve this.

I can sotre user/pass in session but that is just stupid. Why attached session exists if I have to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After trying to figure about this rid plus+1 etc I noticed that rid is changing on presence, on message on message sent on roster on roster change so I made a XMLHttpRequest on each to remember new rid in session. For some reason localstorage is sometimes working sometimes not.

Now i have rid up to date all the time.

---

I think I got this. Problem was in rid and presence.

1) First you have to figure out from your logs if your rid is increasing or decreasing.

My was decreasing by one. So I substract -1 from my Chat.connection.rid

2) In my openfire logs I figured out that I was sending unavailable status on page refresh
so I changed my window.unload function to send presence to online. N

Now I am refreshing page million times and i never got disconnected.

Now I just have to figure out how to remember connection.rid to localStorage for non HTML browsers.

To start openfire in debug mode you just add ./openfire.sh -debug. Then  you will be able to se everything in debug.log

This did trick for me. If this is doing trick for you please +1 and accept answer.

**Do not forget to terminate session on logout :)**

UPDATE

This is my on window.onunload function

```
window.onunload = function(ev){

    var initialPresence = $pres().c('show').t("cao").up().c('status').t("sad");

        Chat.connection.send(initialPresence);
        store.set('session_rid', parseInt(Chat.connection.rid)-1);

        //save rooster contacts state
        var contacts = document.getElementById('records').getElementsByTagName('li');
        var id_value;
        var class_value;
        var status;
        var el;
        for(i= 0; i < contacts.length; i++){

            el = contacts[i].getElementsByClassName("mood")[0];
            status = el.textContent || el.innerText;
            Array.prototype.slice.call(contacts[i].attributes).forEach(function(item) {

            if(item.name == "id"){
               id_value = item.value;
            }
            if(item.name == "class"){
               class_value = item.value;
            }
            store.set('user'+i, { id: id_value, class_name: class_value, status : status });

            });

        }
       Chat.disconnect();
}
```

This is my on window.onload function

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(store.get("session_rid")){

       var obj; 
       var id;
       var class_name;
       var status;

        store.forEach(function(val, key) {
            if(val !== "session_rid"){

                setTimeout(function(){
                obj = eval(key);
                id = obj.id;
                class_name = obj.class_name;
                status = obj.status;
                    if(document.getElementById(id)){
                         document.getElementById(id).className = class_name;
                         document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("mood")[0].innerHTML = "<span>"+status+"</span>";
                    }
                }, 1000);


            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is working for me. I used [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/) to store data so it can work on IE.

I used attached sessions.

```
//json is from ajax call on some php script that has started attached session on user login
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE); 
    connection.attach(obj.fulljid,   
                      obj.sid,   
                      (store.get("session_rid") ? store.get("session_rid"):obj.rid),     
                      justDoIt);
     full_jid = obj.fulljid;
```

Comment: hi @pregmatch, im having this problem myself and i could not find any solution. My RID is increasing by 1, how did you attach your RID, in your case minus 1 to the existing connection? how did you send an online presence when page unloads? I stored my RID, SID to a cookie. please help.

Comment: @nino, tell me if you need further assistance and accept or +1 answer if this is working for you.

Comment: @pregmatch I am facing similar issue with my code...although I am still not able to figure out. Will you please have a look at this question and see if your could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763578/resuming-xmpp-connection-upon-page-refresh